# как отладить страницу jsp, и где найти исходный код jsp страницы в IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsp, jstl, tag

Доброе время суток.

Разбираюсь с jsp страницами, подскажите как jsp страницы преобразуются в обычные классы, и как их отладить?

В стеке вызовов есть явный вызов метода класса _jspService:19, index_jsp, но отладить в классическом понимании (с точкой останова) не могу
а вот, _jspx_meth_alex_005ffoton_005fout_005ffoton_005f0:19, index_jsp, это при вызове тэга

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот JSP страница(taglib c prefix = "alex_foton" моя библиотека, для понимания механизма тэгов):

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="alex_foton" uri="http://alex-foton.com" %>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test/debug JSP </title>
  </head>

  <body>

  <alex_foton:out_foton/>

  </body> 

</html>
```

Вот тэг, но он я думаю мало сам по себе интересен:

```
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport;

public class OutFoton extends TagSupport {

      public OutFoton() {

           int dfsf= 6;

      }

     @Override
     public int doStartTag() throws JspException {

          return super.doStartTag();

     }
}
```

Comment: Надо загрузить/подключить исходные коды сервера приложений. Но обычно это не требуется для понимания механизмов тэгов. Если Вы конечно не пытаетесь реализовать свой движок jsp. Но в этом случае Вы точно знали бы что где и почём.

Comment: вот на этой странице http://java-online.ru/jsp-example.xhtml, есть пример начинается с "Исходный код сервлета index_jsp.java", но для idea не могу найти

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем, ответ такой.

Исходный код в idea лежит в папке пользователя системы, по пути вроде этого:

*Пользователь*.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_web_jstl_work\work\Catalina\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java

Ответ на второй вопрос, как отладить. Для нужно взять этот исходник, и поместить его к себе в проект, дальше через мэппинг настраиваем путь к сервелету, далее отлаживаем

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>index_jsp</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```